# Is there a way to get all ManyToMany related objects in DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have Tags in my application and it's possible to Tag different things like News, Events...
News and Events have a ManyToMany relation to Tags. Is it possible to get every object where the Tag is used?

My Models (shortened) look like this:

Tag Model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
```

News Model

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="news")
```

Event Model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="event")
```

I know that I can get all News that have the Tags assigned by

```
tag = self.get_object()
tag.news.all()
```

But is it possible to get all News, Events... without 10 requests? I'm looking for something like `tag.all.all()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tag.news.all() | tag.event.all()
```

"news" and "event" are accessible due to reverse relationship here which are defined in their respective model fields with the keyword "related_name".

note that this may give duplicate tags as it is a union between the two.
for distinct tags,

```
(tag.news.all() | tag.event.all()).distinct()
```

Comment: Is there also a possibility to achieve that without knowing what Models have a ManyToMany relation to Tags? So i can just go for and add a new Model with a ManyToMany relation to Tags and don't have to edit the tagsView everytime.